# After changing resolution of screen, mouse and UI behaving weird

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, resize, screen-resolution

I'm developing a game with Unity3D. In game I added option to change screen resolution. Firstly, this is my code:

```
void Start ()
{
    Resolution[] resolutions = Screen.resolutions;
}

public void SetResolution(int index)
{
    Screen.SetResolution(resolutions[index].width, resolutions[index].height,Screen.fullScreen);
}
```

When I change resolution with a smaller resolution, screen become blue. If I change with a bigger one UI objects streching out of screen, but still I can click them on their initial positions. And for normal objects too. In summary, screen changing (not correctly) but mouse behaving according to normal resolution.

I had this problem when I developing a simple project like paint with OpenGL. When I resize screen, mouse start behaving incorrect. But I don't know if they are same issues.

P.S. Im using only 16:9 aspect ratio for screen, so there is no aspect ratio changing problem!

Comment: Have you tried CanvasScaler component?   http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.CanvasScaler.html

Comment: Thanks for help but it was not about Canvas. Because when I resize window manually it behaves normal. I tought there is something missing about calling "redraw window." in graphics. Then I update graphic driver and Unity3D. And problem fixed.